# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Content of HTML file not displayed

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-console

I have recently downloaded the IBM Worklight Developer edition from the Eclipse Marketplace.

In order to deploy the app when I right-click on the HTML file and choose `Run As > Run On Server`. It then asks me to select `Localhost` which is running on my machine. When the index.html file is displayed in the window, a blank page comes and the contents of the `body` of my HTML file are not visible.

I am unable to build and deploy and run any project in IBM Worklight.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not working for you, because you are doing it wrong...
[Read the IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/) before jumping headlong into Worklight...

After creating a new Worklight project and application, you need to:

1. Right-click the Worklight `application`
2. And choose `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`
3. Then you right-click on the Worklight `project`
4. And choose `Open Worklight Console`

Now you can preview your application.
[Read the training materials](http://www-01.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/library/).

[image]

Comment: Thank You :) It worked I had this problem because previously I was using Build All and Deploy Option on Run As and now i was selecting run as on the html file instead of the folder in the apps folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try this also.

After creating a new Worklight project and application, you need to:

1. Right-click the Worklight application

   And choose Run As > Build All Environments.

   Then And choose Run As > Preview

This will open your application in the browser

Hope this helps