# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Not able to see Run and Deploy action

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am creating my first application using IBM worklight.
I am using Eclipse Juno in Ubuntu 12.04

I have created a hello world project to test, but when i right click and select Run I am not able to see Run and Deploy what is see in Preview and Run configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you right-click on the APPLICATION folder and choose `Run As > Run on Worklight Development Server`.

See my full answer to the same question, here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Content of HTML file not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030629/ibm-worklight-6-1-content-of-html-file-not-displayed)