# Worklight 6.1 preview is not loading WLJQ

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I've tried the solution in this page [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Content of HTML file not displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21030629/ibm-worklight-6-1-content-of-html-file-not-displayed) and it didn't work for me.

[image: WL libraries not being compiled or included in the preview]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try deleting the wlBuildResources folder.
See my answer here: [IBM Worklight 6.1 - Failed re-generating the iPhone native folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21008162/ibm-worklight-6-1-failed-re-generating-the-iphone-native-folder/)

1. Close Eclipse
2. Locate your temp folder ([Windows](http://appscout.pcmag.com/microsoft-windows/272405-find-the-temp-folder-in-vista-and-windows-7), [OS X](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/3949/how-do-i-find-out-the-system-temporary-directory))
3. Delete the `wlBuildResources` folder
4. Open Eclipse
5. Re-build

Comment: Excellent!  This worked.  Thank you.  How often would we need to delete this folder?  I haven't had to do it before so just wondering. Thank you, again!

Comment: Hopefully never again.